# iOS app using OAuth2 with Google and Safari presents open page dialog

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, oauth-2.0

I have finally got my iPhone app to authenticate and return back to my app with the authorisation code. The main problem was that the reverse client id did not get picked up by my app. I had to add an url scheme of my bundle id instead of the reverse client id.

Anywho, the problem is post authenticating in Safari I am presented with a open 'app name' page dialog. If the user clicks open it works fine. If they leave it for just a few seconds it redirects them to the Google homepage and they have to start all over again. If they are using two factor authentication by any other method than phone call I think it fails too.

How can I avoid this open page dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use the official Google library for iOS. This does not involve Safari like the AeroGear library I was using does.